# How to add a where clause to a statement with a known column name in SQLAlchemy 0.9?

Tags: python, sql, reflection, sqlalchemy

There is a set of tables, all of which have a column with a determined name, say 'ColA'.  I'm trying to write a function which will a attach a specific `where` clause to a SqlAlchemy statement (`Insert`, `Select`, `Update`) for that column.

**Desired result:**

I'd like the result to work like this (where the function I need is `somehow_get_table`):

```
def attach_where(statement, val):
    return statement.where(somehow_get_table(statement).c.ColA == val)

statement = select([table1.c.col1, table1.c.col2])

print statement
>>> SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1

print attach_where(statement, 1)
>>> SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE ColA = 1
```

**Possible solutions I've thought of:**

1. Get the list of `Column` objects from the statement and select one (or all) of the tables to which the column belongs and use that for the `where`.
2. Use only the column name (as in text).  I'm not sure how to do this, and it might break for some cases (like joins).

I think number 1 is better but I could be wrong, and I feel like there should be a better to do this.  What is a good pattern to do this?

Comment: Maybe following Recipies could be helpful: [PreFilteredQuery](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery) and [GlobalFilter](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/GlobalFilter), although they both take care only about the `select` part (`Query` actually).